# paperclip image not loading when using "select" in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, paperclip, haml

In my controller, I get movies with:

```
movies = Movie.active.includes(:likes).references(:likes).where("likes.user_id = ?", user.id).joins(:collections).active.uniq
```

I then order and filter them:

```
@movies = movies.order(query_order).offset(offset).limit(limit + 1)
```

This output in an PG:Error: `PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

I quickly found at that you have to **select** the fields you order by. So I added `.select("movies.*, likes.*")` to the query.

```
movies = Movie.select("movies.*, likes.*").active.includes(:likes).references(:likes).where("likes.user_id = ?", user.id).joins(:collections).active.uniq
```

It works fine except now Paperclip messes up big time. The HTML gets rendered **exactly** the same as before, but somehow the image doesn't show/process.

```
=image_tag movie.cover.url(:expanded), :class => "expanded"
```

When I remove `.select("movies.*, likes.*")` and `.uniq` from the query it has duplicate items, but the images work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I joined `movies` with `likes` it both retrieved the `movie.id` and the `likes.id`.

This this paperclip helper couldn't cope with two `id's` so it randomly picked the `likes` id.

```
=image_tag movie.cover.url(:expanded), :class => "expanded"
```

As a result wrong paths got created: iE. `/movies/system/007/movie_with_id_01_image.jpg`.

I had to change my `select` clause, now excluding the `likes.id`.

```
.select("movies.*, likes.*")
.select("movies.*, likes.column_a, likes.column_b, ... , likes.column_x")
```

Now it finally worked again.